# How to remove two object at the same time using command line from an Arraylist

Tags: java, arrays

I have one list now.
I want to remove two object when I used command line.

```
 Ex)
    javac Main.java
    
    java Main 2 3 
 a v i
```

I try changed code .I can not do that.
Please help me.

**Condition**

using Arraylist

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] s = {"a", "v", "c", "e", "i"};
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(s.length);
        for (String string : s) {
            list.add(string);
        }
        try {
                int index = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
                
                list.remove(index);
                for (String string : list) 
                System.out.println(string);
        } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            System.out.println("it is not good");
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
            System.out.println("it is not good");
        }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            System.out.println("it is not good");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my answer. Please take note of the changes @Masa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code. Your code only takes ONE argument args[0]. Instead I used a for loop to iterate all given arguments. However, this will not work in the way you are thinking, because the index is shifted when an item is removed.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] s = {"a", "v", "c", "e", "i"};
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(s.length);
        for (String string : s) {
            list.add(string);
        }
        try {
            for (int i = 0; i< args.length; i++){
                int index = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
                list.remove(index);
            }
            
            for (String string : list)
                System.out.println(string);
        } catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            System.out.println("it is not good");
        }catch (IllegalArgumentException e){
            System.out.println("it is not good");
        }catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
            System.out.println("it is not good");
        }
    }
```

Instead, if you use the following, it adjusts the indexes from the arguments provided based on the number of items removed.

```
for (int i = 0; i< args.length; i++){
                int index = Integer.parseInt(args[i])-i;
                list.remove(index);
            }
```

I just realised the code does not account for indexes that are not sorted. Thus, I added some code that will perform the sorting for you. Use the following code instead.

```
int[] numbers = Arrays.stream(args).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray(); //convert args to int array
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));  //shows your arguments
Arrays.sort(numbers);  //sort your indexes in ascending order
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));  //shows sorted arguments

for (int i = 0; i< numbers.length; i++){
    list.remove(numbers[i] - i);
}

for (String string : list)
    System.out.println(string);
```

note, if you dont want to use `numbers[i]-i` you could instead iterate the array starting from the back of the array and use numbers[i] instead

```
for (int i = numbers.length-1; i>=0; i--){
       list.remove(numbers[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kindness.

I have a question.

How to remove element from ArrayList  without shift elements.

Comment: You cant remove something from an arraylist without shifting the indexes of elements remaining.